# Storing data with Python arrays (HAR-RV Credit Risk model implementation)

Tags: python, risk-analysis

that's my first time here at Stack and I'm on my first days with Python.
I'm dealing with the HAR-RV model, trying to run this equation but having no success at all to store my operations on the array

Here what I'm trying to calculate:

> r_[t,i] = Y_[t,i] - Y_[t,i-1]

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/30/299a4ab026de7db33c4222b30f3ed70a-full.png

Im using the first relation here, where "r" means return and "Y" the stock prices

```
t = 10 # daily intervals

i = 30 # number of days

s = 1

# (Here I've just created some fake numbers, intending to simulate some stock prices)

Y = abs(np.random.random((10,30)) + 1)  

# initializing my return array
return = np.array([])

# (I also tried to initialize it as a Matrix before..) : 
return = np.zeros((10,30))

# here is my for loop to store each daily return at its position on the "return" Array. I wanted an Array  but got just "() size"

for t in range(0,9):    
    for i in range(1,29):                                  
        return = np.array( Y.item((t,i)) - Y.item((t,i-1)) )
```

... so, I was expecting something like this:

return = [first difference, second difference, third difference...]

how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first don't use `return` as a variable name in python as it is a python keyword (it signifies the result of a function). I have changed your variable `return` to `ret_val`.

You are wanting to make a change at each position in your array, so make the following change to your for loop:

```
for t in range(0,10):
    for i in range(1,30):
        ret_val[t][i] = Y[t][i] - Y[t][i-1]
print(ret_val)
```

This is saying to change the value at index `ret_val[t][i]` with the result of subtracting the values at that specific index in `Y`. You should see an array of the same shape when you print.

Also, the `range` function in python does not include the upper number. So when you say, `for i in range(0,9)` you are saying to include numbers `0-8`. For your array, you'll want to do `for i in range(0,10)` to include all values in your array. Correspondingly, you'll want to do the same `for i in range(1,30)`.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I've already tried something  with "var[a][b]" notation, but got some errors, probably because of my incorrect loop range.

* On the original code I've used "retorno" (Portuguese word) instead of "return", I've just translated it to english for clarity purposes. Thanks for your advice :)